# Omission of the preposition "of" in chemical procedure desciptions: "transfer 1.5 g bovine milk powder".. etc

Tags: prepositions, terminology

From a procedures section in a document:

> Transfer 1.5 g bovine milk powder into a 200 ml volumetric beaker.

Is it common practice to omit **of** in construction of the kind

> 1.5 g (of) bovine milk powder

I have the impression that it is, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe there's some book describing this condensed style of writing, and this omission of prepositions is mentioned there, but I haven't found a clear mention by googling.

Neither did I find any discussions of this on language-related websites.

Comment: I have seen it, e.g. "introduce 10mg saline [solution]", so it is probably common usage in highly technical documents. For more general readers, I would use a preposition.

Comment: @Mick it's also pretty much ubiquitous in cooking recipes. I guess it's just the case of terseness and the ability to quickly skim the text for information being more important than proper grammar.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Cooking recipes **are** highly technical (for me). Don't get me wrong. I **can** microwave a curry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the preposition "of" is definitely grammatically correct; its omission is widely accepted and understood in that context, technical (field of Chemistry) English.